# How do I tell which faction a pandaren player belongs to?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In Mists of Pandaria, both factions can choose the Pandaren race.

How can I tell if a Pandaren player is horde or alliance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All players, as of Mists of Pandaria, now have their faction included in the tooltip:

[image]

If you're suitably knowledgeable about armour rewards and looks, you will sometimes be able to tell by the style of armour they are wearing as well.

Comment: I was fighting a boss, couldn't write, but you updated the answer to the correct answer before I could end the fight and post

Comment: My previous answer was 100% correct.  It just didn't include the easiest way (the beta finally finished downloading its update and I got in).

Comment: ... if it was 100% correct whey did you need to edit it?

Comment: Because, to quote myself, it "didn't include the easiest way".

Answer (score 2):

In PVP, the most intuitive way of knowing wether a Pandaren is part of your faction is by checking their nameplate. If theirs is colored Blue, they are part of your faction.

Additionally, in MoP the faction information will be included in the tooltip whenever you mouseover on any player.

Comment: Isn't everyone blue in neutral zones (on PvE servers)?

Comment: As long as they aren't flagged for PVP and you're not flagged either.